# query to display a row data as column

Tags: sql-server

I need a query to execute record of row as columns, 
eg: row  holds data as  `'101,102,103,104'`.

Result should be:

```
101
102
103
104
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [splitting a single row into multi rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630435/splitting-a-single-row-into-multi-rows)

Answer (score 1):

you can check [switching-rows-and-columns-in-sql](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/switching-rows-and-columns-in-sql/)